# Ask different badges to product on Shopify?

Tags: php, css, shopify

The ideal is that I want to add some badge to product on Shopify, like "sale", "new", or "today only".

If product match the condition, it will appear a "new" or "sale" badge else it will not display any badge.

I've search the internet for solution but it's not clear enough for me to understand.

I'm new with Shopify so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. figure out the condition that will trigger '**sale**', '**new**' or '**today only**'. Could be a tag, price or other thing, but that is up to you to learn, from studying the basics of Shopify Products.
2. design a badge, and learn how to present it, likely with some css and js (show/hide/append/prepend etc) and just pure Liquid
3. edit your Liquid templates so that when these conditions are found, you render the badge that matches.

Does not get much simpler, although concepts like '**today only**' could be some manual labour for you.